# Improve performance of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, supervised-learning, matplotlib

I have written some code for an SVM and the final output isn’t brilliant. [image] The data is linearly separable so I don’t understand why the data isn’t perfectly separated. Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, numpy as np

x = np.array([[-2, 4, -1], [4, 1, -1], [1, 6, -1], [2, 4, -1], [6, 2, -1]])

y = np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1, 1])

def svm_sgd(X, Y):
    w = np.zeros(len(X[0]))    # Parameters 
    eta = 1
    epochs = 100000

    # Update rules

    for epoch in range(1, epochs):
        for i, x in enumerate(X):
            if (Y[i] * np.dot(X[i], w)) < 1:
                w = w + eta * ((X[i] * Y[i]) + (-2 * (1/epoch) * w))
            else:
                w = w + eta * (-2 * (1/epoch) * w)
    return w

w = svm_sgd(x, y)
print(w)

# Print Hyperplane —————————————

for d, sample in enumerate(x):
    if d < 2:
        plt.scatter(sample[0], sample[1], s=120, marker='_', linewidths=2)
    else:
        plt.scatter(sample[0], sample[1], s=120, marker='+', linewidths=2)

plt.scatter(2,2, s=120, marker='_', linewidths=2, color='yellow')
plt.scatter(4,3, s=120, marker='+', linewidths=2, color='blue')

x2=[w[0],w[1],-w[1],w[0]]
x3=[w[0],w[1],w[1],-w[0]]

x2x3 = np.array([x2,x3])
X,Y,U,V = zip(*x2x3)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(X,Y,U,V,scale=1, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

The bottom portion just uses matplotlib to print the data, so it’s not part of the SVM algorithm, and can therefore be ignored.

> The problem ~ can anyone explain to me, based on my code, why the line doesn’t separate the data more perfectly?

Comment: Try to replace `1/epoch` with `1.0/epoch` - this is important for Python 2.x, in Python 3.x it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

This is the output when I run your code. It seems to be doing fine.

[image]

```
[  1.58876117   3.17458055  11.11863105]
```

Try to run it again? Perhaps you changed some parameters accidentally before posting it?

Comment: Thank you. The weight vector I received was rounded to 1 number; yours looks much more precise. It could possibly be the fact I’m using python 2.7 or a different version of numpy that’s rounding the weight vector/not storing a significant enough value

Comment: Ah, i see, i was using python 3 most likely there is some subtle difference somewhere with one of the library.